# Setting the color of the secondary Y-Axis on embedded Chart in Google Sheets using script

Tags: javascript, colors, embedded, axis, yaxis

I am trying to change the color of the Right Y-Axis text from Apps Script. I have a chart template which is called by multiple functions with varying numbers of series. If I need to add a right Y-Axis, the calling routing selects the chart and changes the designated series to Y-Axis 1. this works fine. The issue I have is that, for presentation purposes the background is black and so is the secondary Y axis text. I have been unable to find how to code to change the color.

The following code executes without error but does not achieve the desired result. I believe it only applies to the primary Y-axis

```
  var i = 0;
  /**  Loop through the charts  */
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    /**  Select each chart */
    var cht = (charts[i]);
    sh.getCharts().forEach(cht => {
      const container = cht.getContainerInfo();
      if (container.getAnchorRow() == row && container.getAnchorColumn() == col) {
        /** We now have the chart  */

        var title = cht.getOptions().get('title')
        cht = cht.modify()
          // .textStyle().setColor('white').setFontSize(12)
          /** The following works but we cannot use variables in setOption */
          //.setOption('series', { 12: { textStyle: { color: 'yellow', fontName: 'Calibri', fontSize: 14, visibleInLegend: true }, lineWidth: 4, targetAxisIndex: 1 } })
          //  .setYAxisTextStyle().setColor('white').setFontSize(12)
          .setOption('YAxis', { 1:{TextStyle: {color: 'white',fontName: 'Calibri', fontSize: 14}}})
          .build();
        sh.updateChart(cht);
      }
    })
    break;
  }
```